# O que poderia causar a parada em um FOR? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

estou com um problema em um script, o mesmo para em um FOR e não executa o resto do i.

No caso se encontra nessa linha: `for (i = 1; i < ultimoId;i++) {`

linha 43 se forem olhar em algum Ide.

Segue o script:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {


    var conf = [{
        codigo: "",
        desconto: "",
        string: "",
        auxString: "",
        auxNum: "",
        descontoNum: "",
        auxDesconto: "",
        valorFinal: "",
        auxFinal2: "",
        valorFinalDesconto: "",
        idInicial: ""
    }];

    function apenasNumeros(string) {
        var numsStr2 = string.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        return parseInt(numsStr2);
    };

    function apenasNumeros2(desconto) {
        var InternoDesconto = desconto.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        return parseInt(InternoDesconto);
    };

    var i = "";
    var j = "";
    var string = "";
    var auxString = "";
    var auxNum = "";
    var desconto = "";
    var descontoNum = "";
    var auxDesconto = "";
    var valorFinalDesconto = "";
    var valorFinal = "";
    var auxFinal2 = "";
    var resultado = "";

    var ultimoId = $(".shelfNewPriceWrapper").attr("id");
    j = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < ultimoId;i++) {

        string = $("#" + i + "").html();
        auxString = apenasNumeros(string);

        auxNum = auxString / 100;

        desconto = $(".highlightWrapper p").html();

        descontoNum = apenasNumeros2(desconto);

        auxDesconto = descontoNum / 100;

        valorFinalDesconto = (auxNum * auxDesconto);
        valorFinal = (auxNum) - (valorFinalDesconto);
        auxFinal2 = valorFinal.toFixed(2);

        conf[j].codigo = i;
        conf[j].desconto = desconto;
        conf[j].string = string;
        conf[j].auxString = auxString;
        conf[j].auxNum = auxNum;
        conf[j].descontoNum = descontoNum;
        conf[j].auxDesconto = auxDesconto;
        conf[j].valorFinal = valorFinal;
        conf[j].auxFinal2 = auxFinal2;
        conf[j].valorFinalDesconto = valorFinalDesconto;

        resultado = conf[j].auxFinal2;
        console.log("indice:" + j);
       
        $("#" + i + "").html('R$ ' + resultado + ' ');
        j++;
        

        string = "";
        auxString = "";
        auxNum = "";
        desconto = "";
        descontoNum = "";
        auxDesconto = "";
        valorFinalDesconto = "";
        valorFinal = "";
        auxFinal2 = "";
        resultado = "";

    };
        

});
```

O que poderia estar acontecendo para que ele nao execute esse FOR ?

SEGUE O CÓDIGO HTML - DETALHE USAMOS VTEX

```html
#set($id = $product.Id)
#set($uri = $product.Uri)
#set($escapedName = $product.HtmlEscapedName)
#set($evaluationRate = $product.EvaluationRate) 

<!-- class: shelf prateleira vitrine home -->
<div class="shelfImageWrapper">
 <div class="shelfButtonWrapper">
  <div class="shelfAmountInCart">
   $product.AmountInCart
  </div>
  <!--<div class="shelfBuyButtomWrapper">
   $product.BottomBuyAsynchronous
  </div>-->
 </div>
 <a class="shefImage" title="$escapedName" rel="nofollow" href="$uri">
  <div class="shelfImage-1">$product.GetImageTag(235,235)</div>
 
 </a>
</div>

<div class="shelfInformationWrapper">
 <input type="hidden" value="$product.BestPrice" class="qd_productPrice" />
 <input type="hidden" value="$product.ListPrice" class="qd_productOldPrice" />
 <input type="hidden" value="$product.NumbersOfInstallment" class="qd_sp_installments" />
 <h3><a title="$escapedName" href="$uri" rel="nofollow">$product.Name</a></h3>
 #if ($product.IsInStock)
  <div class="yv-review-quickreview" value="$id"></div>
  <p class="shelfPriceWrapper">
   <a title="$escapedName" rel="nofollow" href="$uri">
    #if ($product.HasBestPrice)
     <span class="shelfOldPriceWrapper">De $product.ListPrice</span>
     <br/>
    #end
   Por <span class="shelfNewPriceWrapper" id="$id">$product.BestPrice </span> <span>à vista</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="installmentWrapper">
     #if ($product.NumbersOfInstallment > 1)
      em até
      <strong class="installment"> ${product.NumbersOfInstallment}x </strong> 
      de
      <strong class="InstallmentValue"> $product.InstallmentValue </strong> 
      <span>s/juros</span>
     #end
    </span>
     #if ($product.HasBestPrice)
      <span class="saveAmount">economize <span class="qd_saveAmount">R$ </span> <small>(</small><span class="qd_saveAmountPercent">%</span><small>)</small></span>
     #end
   </a>
    $product.BottomBuyAsynchronous
  </p>
 #else
  <p class="outOfStock">Produto Indisponível</p> 
 #end
</div>
#if ($product.IsInStock)
 <div class="shelfStampsWrapper">
  <a title="Clique para ver as condições de frete" class="highlightWrapper" rel="nofollow" href="#" data-reveal-id="frete-gratis-vitrine" data-animation="fade">$product.HightLight</a>
  <a title="$escapedName" class="highlightWrapper" rel="nofollow" href="$uri">$product.DiscountHightLight</a>
 </div>
#end
```

Comment: Qual o **ID** do campo que contém essa classe `shelfNewPriceWrapper` ?

Comment: Penso que o problema pode ser o facto de `ultimoId` ser uma _string_. Testa assim: `ultimoId = parseInt(ultimoId, 10);` na linha anterior a `for (i = 1; i < ultimoId;i++) {`

Comment: porque o i começa com 1 ? o correto seria com 0

Comment: De acordo com a [documentação do attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) ele *"retorna o valor do atributo do primeiro elemento selecionado"*. Então se você tiver mais de um elemento com a classe `.shelfNewPriceWrapper` pode ser que ele não tenha o id que você deseje.

Comment: O ID do shelfNewPriceWrapper eu fiz outros script para gerar o ID no caso é um ID diferente para cado um que gera

Comment: Converta a variavel ultimoId para int que deve funcionar.

Comment: @Thadeu converti para comentário a tua resposta por ser curta demais  e melhor se enquadrar como um comentário. Eu também acho que seja esse o caso [como comentei em cima](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87718/o-que-poderia-causar-a-parada-em-um-for-javascript#comment176934_87718). Vamos ver o que o Julio diz...

Comment: é melhor você declarar seu for assim: `for (var i = 1; i < ultimoId;i++) {...}` também não faz muito sentido isso:  `$("#" + i + "").html(..` ... pode fazer só isso: `$('#' + i).html(...`

Comment: aqui também `...).html('R$ ' + resultado);`

Comment: Publique sua HTML como vc quer que seja a saída, pois seu código além de mal feito está muito confuso.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com o post do HTML, espero que ajude.

Comment: @JulioSantos conseguiste resolver este problema? se não junta por favor o HTML renderizado e não somente o que está no servidor.

Comment: Olá Sérgio consegui resolver esse problema de outra forma, irei estar postando o script.

Answer (score 1):

consegui resolver o problema de meu código da seguinte forma:

```js
"undefined" != typeof jQuery && jQuery(".flag").each(function() {
  var e = jQuery(this);
  if (e.is(':contains(",")') || e.is(':contains(".")')) {
    var t = e.html();
    t = t.split(" - ");
    var r, i = t[0];
    i = jQuery.trim(i), "%" == i.substr(i.length - 1, 1) ? (i = i.substr(0, i.length - 1), r = "%") : (i = i.substr(2), r = "R$"), i = jQuery.trim(i), i = i.replace(",", "."), i = Number(i);
    var a = e.parents(".data").find(".bestPrice").html();
    if (a = jQuery.trim(a), a = a.substr(3), a = a.replace(",", "."), a = Number(a), "%" == r) {
      var s = a * i / 100,
        n = Math.ceil(a - s);
      n = n.toFixed(2)
    } else if ("R$" == r) {
      var n = Math.ceil(a - i);
      n = n.toFixed(2)
    }
    e.parents(".data").find(".bestPrice").html("R$" + n), e.html(t[1])
  }
});
```